# PHP regex robust splitting by comma, ignoring quoted items

Tags: php, regex

I would like to robustly split a list by commas. As-is, [`preg_split`](https://www.php.net/preg_split) is accomplishing the basic goal. The user can enter any combination of `[space(s)],[space(s)]` between items and the list will split out successfully.

```
$items = 'one, two , three  ,four,   five';
$items = preg_split('/(\s*,\s*)+/', $items);
```

**This results** in `['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']` correctly. I would like to augment this to allow for *escaped* delimiters via quotations, e.g.:

```
$items = 'one, "two , three",four,   five';
```

**Desired result** of `['one', 'two , three', 'four', 'five']`

I believe the answer is in [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php), but can't seem to put the puzzle pieces together with the unique `[space(s)],[space(s)]` constraint.

*Note that [`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) doesn't work in this case, as the spacing will skew the final strings.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're parsing a CSV string, so you can use:

```
$result = str_getcsv( $items);
```

This will result in:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "one"
  [1]=>
  string(11) "two , three"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "four"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "   five"
}
```

You can then remove all of the whitespace surrounding the elements with:

```
$result = array_map( 'trim', $result);
```

Comment: Genius. I was totally over-thinking! :D Will accept when possible.

Comment: does this work for special characters? since, str_getcsv removes first occurence of special character if special character is first letter